# HTML questions here or on webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Do we answer HTML questions here, or refer them to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com?

I am not talking about web programming questions... but questions about strictly HTML and CSS.  To me, clear-cut presentation layer questions belong on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

An example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287130/html-select-box-does-not-scale-in-ie

Is that proper SO material, or should it be moved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow or DocType is the best place for those type of questions. Webmasters does not deal with code; rather, it focuses on more general concepts like SEO.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't even know about DocType.  It seems very different and disconnected from the other SE sites.  I am assuming these types of questions on Webmasters be directed to DocType then?  Seems odd that we have two places for them.  Why not direct all HTML/CSS only questions to DocType?

Comment: DocType is not actually a SE site; it is rather an affiliated site. The SE site for HTML is Stack Overflow. @Brad

Comment: thanks, this answers my question!  And here, I thought Pekka had gone crazy.  :-)  Sorry Pekka!

Comment: @Brad no problem. I think technically, you're right, HTML and CSS don't really belong. But they've been there since the start, and I imagine they generate a *huge* portion of the site's traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I move that with 28,500 questions, this falls under the "Grandfather with a twenty foot beard" clause. :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you define HTML+CSS as code.

Since today's web is so JavaScript centric through and through, I am inclined to rule that it's close enough.

Comment: The term "HTML code" and "CSS code" have been around since these "languages" themselves. HTML - hypertext markup language as we know. Language => Code (in programming context). And CSS is imo just abstracting out some portions of HTML and making them more modular.

Answer (score 0):

I guess with all programming, there's what the code does, and how it does it. A question about a particle simulation program is programming if it's about how the code works, and it's physics if it's about what the code does. A question about a website is webmasters if it's about website logic and design, and it's stackoverflow if it's about syntax and semantics of HTML and CSS.