# What's the deal with migrating CSS questions to Webmasters?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

Yesterday, this question was migrated to Webmasters by five users: 
[Two divs, one fixed width, the other, the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487085/two-divs-one-fixed-width-the-other-the-rest)

I flagged it with the text:

> Why was this migrated? The migration
>   makes no sense to me, can it be
>   reversed? Thanks

and it was promptly moved back to Stack Overflow (with the "migration history" cleared).

That's all good.

So today, I noticed this (admittedly poor quality) question had been migrated to Webmasters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509271/ie-issues-with-my-website-help-me-fix-my-css?noredirect=1

I flagged it with the text:

> I think this question was wrongly
>   migrated.

..and the flag was dismissed as invalid :( <sub>Now I'll have to flag another 9001 things to get back to 750 flag weight :o</sub>

**There's evidently confusion somewhere.** What's going on here?

Relevant:

- [What is the status of HTML/CSS layout questions on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85675/what-is-the-status-of-html-css-layout-questions-on-so)
- [HTML questions here or on webmasters.stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71006/html-questions-here-or-on-webmasters-stackexchange-com)
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894?tab=offtopic&phase=definition#tab-top

<sup>It's possibly also worth noting that in both cases, the first close vote was by [the same user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600500/palo-ebermann).</sup>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That migrated question was terrible, it should have been closed as "too localized".

I don't think it was wrongly migrated, I think it never should have been migrated at all. What's the first rule of <s>fight club</s> question migration?

### Never. Migrate. Crap.

Relevant [meta.webmasters discussion](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/web-development-question-migrated-to-stackoverflow):

> I think some HTML questions can be OK [on pro webmasters], but **in general [pro webmasters] is at a higher level of "website" not "code that renders pages"**. It's not that pro webmasters don't code, it's that they have bigger scaling problems to solve than coding HTML for a single page.

based on that I updated the [Pro Webmasters faq](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) to include

> Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it *might* be a better fit on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). We prefer questions here about problems or issues that affect **entire websites**.

also see:
[The final reckoning: HTML/CSS questions](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/504/the-final-reckoning-html-css-questions)

Comment: Can we get "Never migrate crap" (or similar) added to the migrate dialog? I know most people won't read it, but at least if it's there we can point to it as visible documentation of this rule. And if it stops a few people posting that first migrate vote then it will be worth it.