# Allow moderator migration of old questions between non-trilogy sites

Tags: discussion, migration, old-questions

I recently came across https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2678/104 , a question that is very interesting, but is (IMO) off-topic for Skeptics.SE and on-topic for History.SE .

The main post about migrating old questions is [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

The justification

> Therefore, I think the real solution is much simpler: just disable the
>   migration of old questions. They're rarely welcomed or heavily
>   improved post-migration, often overtly disliked by folks on the
>   destination site, and can end up causing a rather bad experience for
>   folks who were participating in good faith on the original.

doesn't seem to apply for this question. This question is not [garbage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97000/can-we-try-to-dissuade-some-bad-migrations-by-adding-the-first-rule-to-the-dia), and allowing moderator migration of non-trilogy questions won't open up the floodgates to garbage - by far the majority of garbage is generated on the trilogy sites.

The justification for closing it on Skeptics.SE is so that people new to Skeptics will know what is and isn't on-topic.

The justification for migrating it to History.SE is that if someone's looking for information on the history of great circles, they shouldn't need to search Skeptics.SE for that information. Should they ask the exact same question on History.SE?

Comment: If it were off topic for Skeptics, why didn't they close it yet?

Comment: @slhck Because it was posted when the site was still very young and the scope was not finalized. I've closed it now.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Well, there's a process for getting such questions migrated, wouldn't this be the way to go here? @mad

Comment: @slhck The [process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site) doesn't really work for one question, and it's about migrating questions to graduate sites (History is beta). I think the best course here would be to just re-ask the question on History.