# Questions about JavaScript language, HTML, markups

Tags: discussion, questions

I am a user with a bit only of experience on Maths and TeX-LaTeX SE sites.

I want to post a question about **JavaScript** (the typical "How can I do this ... in JS?") and I wanna be sure where is better to post it: Stack Overflow or programmers Stack Exchange? These two both have JS tags.

I have found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71006/html-questions-here-or-on-webmasters-stackexchange-com) that, for such questions about HTML/CSS, Stack Overflow is the proper one, agreed?

Other SE sites where I can search or ask about **markup** languages in general?

Thanks!

### Edit:

I had not found [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange) when searching before posting, this is very useful to me too. But, for the moment, answer by Joe fills at best to me.

Comment: At first glance, I'd agree that Stack Overflow would be the proper place to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow sounds like the right site for you.  Programmers is the right sight for conceptual questions, not practical ones like the question you note.  SO is for questions about doing specific things in programs or things like programs (including markup languages).

TeX-LaTeX is of course there as you know; other sometimes useful sites include [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) for questions about user interface and [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) for questions about setting up/managing a website (as a professional, on the administration side).

Comment: Well, the more the better, but this was exactly the point of my question. Seen the two edits also, thank you!